# how to test data table in selenium

Tags: selenium, testing, report

I want to test a data in html table.and verify it with database which contains the staff information.  Below is the code.   now i am stuck for creating assert, how to collect the rows or list of list of the table values

@Test

```
public void TestingReport()
{

    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='content']/h2[2]/a")).click(); // click on admin

    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='content']/h2[2]/a")).click(); // click on staff member

    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    //      ArrayList<ArrayList>  ActualReport= new ArrayList<ArrayList>();

    List<WebElement> tablerow =  driver.findElements(By.xpath("//table//tr"));

    ArrayList <String> cellsStr = new ArrayList<>();

    ArrayList<List> table = new ArrayList<>();
    List<WebElement> cells= null ;

  //  System.out.println(tablerow.size());
    for(int i=1;i<tablerow.size();i++) {


         cells = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//tr["+i+"]//td"));


       // table.add(cells);

        for(int j=4;j<cells.size();j++)
        {
            System.out.println(cells.get(j).getText());
            cellsStr.add(cells.get(j).getText());

        }
        System.out.println(cellsStr);

        table.add(cellsStr);
        System.out.println(table);


       System.out.println(cellsStr);


    }


    System.out.println(table);



}
```

Here i am trying to get an Arraylist of sting in to a string, but before the next iteration i am clearing the Arraylist of string, but it is making the List of array list also empty.

Comment: To get the value of cells use the following xpath locator. List<WebElement> cells = tablerow.get(i).findElements(By.xpath("//table/tr["+(i+1)+"]/td"));

Comment: hi i have modified the code as above please go though the question again

Answer (score 0):

Below helps to get the data from list of list of values.

```
List<WebElement> tablerow =  driver.findElements(By.xpath("//table//tr"));
for(int i=1;i<tablerow.size();i++) 
{
List<WebElement> cells= tablerow.get(i).findElements(By.tagName("td"));

for(int j=4;j<cells.size();j++){
List<WebElement> cellSubRow= cells.get(i).findElements(By.tagName("td"));
System.out.println(cellSubRow.get(j).getText());}}
```